# Updating User details in UserDetail Table using One-To-One Relation Django Rest API

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django.
I am trying to update User details in another table using One-To-One relation by following Django document but is giving me an error. Creating a new user is working fine

> Models.py

```
class UserDetails(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=200,default="")
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects=models.Manager()
    def __str__(self):
         return self.user.username
```

> Serializer.py

```
class UserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserDetails
        fields= ['phone','address']
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    userdetails=UserDetailsSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields=['id','url','username','email','password','userdetails']
    def create(self,validated_data):
        user_data=validated_data.pop('userdetails')
        user=User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        UserDetails.objects.create(user=user,**user_data)
        user.save()
        return user

    def update(self,instance,validated_data):
        user_data=validated_data.pop('userdetails')
        user=User.objects.update(**validated_data)
        UserDetails.objects.update(user=user,**user_data)
        user.save()
        return user
```

The error I get - `(1062, "Duplicate entry 'admin' for key 'auth_user.username'")` I know we can update it column by column but I want to update all columns at once as I have a lot of columns. I want a method similar to create.

One more question is that can I combine these create and update as they are doing the same thing?

Comment: `User.objects.update(**validated_data)` you are updating _all_ the models in the database with that query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Abdul Aziz Barkat has mentioned, the way you use your `User` and `UserDetails` model in `update` updates all the rows on those tables.

What you need to do is to *filter* first, and then apply the changes, so something like:

```
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('userdetails')
        instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)
        UserDetails.objects.filter(user=instance).update(**user_data)
        return instance
```

Comment: It is updating UserDetails model but not the User models

Comment: it worked thanks. Can you explain 3rd line?

Comment: That line is to call `ModelSerializer's` update implementation. This means the parent class will do the update for you